# Setting rotating backgrounds in css to not repeat

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to stop my rotating backgrounds from repeating. What am I missing here and where does it need to go? I got the images rotating and linked, but when the backgrounds render, the images repeat.

```css
/* Clickable BG */
$(function() {
        var bgImages = ["bkgd1.png", "bkgd2.png", "bkgd3.png", "bkgd4.png"];
        var indexImage = Math.floor(Math.random() * bgImages.length);
        /*
        setInterval(function(){
                $('body').css('background-image', "url(/css/images/" + bgImages[indexImage] + ")");
                indexImage++;
                if(indexImage == bgImages.length) {
                        indexImage = 0;
                }
        }, 3000);
        */
        $('body').addClass(bgImages[indexImage]).css('background-image', "url(/css/images/" + bgImages[indexImage] + ")");
});

$('.clickableBG').click(function() {
        if($('body').hasClass('bkgd1.png')) {
                window.open("https://www.google.com/", "_self");
        }
        else if($('body').hasClass('bkgd2.png')) {
                window.open("https://www.yahoo.com/");
        }
        else if($('body').hasClass('bkgd3.png')) {
                window.open("https://www.aol.com/");
        }
        else if($('body').hasClass('bkgd4.png')) {
                window.open("https://www.aol.com/");
        }

});

/* Clickable BG */
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand what's your problem but when you mean that the background images repeats in one element then you should use:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

There are other usefull options too:

```
background-color
background-repeat
background-attachment
background-position
```